# SQLite error for creating database

Tags: sqlite, syntax-error

```
SQLite version 3.8.0.2 2013-09-03 17:11:13
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> $sqlite3 DatabaseName.db;
Error: near "$sqlite3": syntax error
sqlite> DatabaseName.db;
Error: near "DatabaseName": syntax error
sqlite> sqlite3 DatabaseName.db;
Error: near "sqlite3": syntax error
sqlite>
```

I am trying to create a database in SQLite. I am getting the error as above. Please help

Comment: Is this [tag:android]? It seams SQLite3 shell.

Comment: post your Database class here...

Comment: @PiyushGupta: Database class... ?

Comment: Means your class in which you have create database.

Comment: sorry I tagged android by mistake. I am writing this in SQLite shell

Comment: How exactly are you starting the `sqlite3` tool?

Comment: @CL.: I've extracted sqlite3.dll, sqlite3.DEF and sqlite3.exe in one folder. Launching the .exe file

Answer (score 13):

`sqlite3 DatabaseName.db` is what you'd use at the command line, not once you've already started the shell.  Running that at command line will open it in the shell with the empty database already open.

When your prompt is `sqlite>`, you're already in the shell.

Here are some docs:  http://sqlite.org/sqlite.html